# How to limit the previous plots?

Tags: plot, tradingview-api

Is there anyway to limit the previous plots?

Let's say I want the script to plot last week's Open and Close, but not the previous ones.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible problem or code.

Comment: Hey, 
here is a sample code, what is does is it paints ALL previous Mondays' opens and closes, I just want to see this week and the previous.

Comment: //title
study(title="Monday_Range", shorttitle="Monday_Range", overlay=true)

// holds the daily price levels
openPrice = security(tickerid, 'D', open)
highPrice = security(tickerid, 'D', high)
lowPrice  = security(tickerid, 'D', low)
midPrice  = avg(highPrice, lowPrice)

Comment: //function which is called by plot to establish day of the week is monday return true or false
isMonday() => dayofweek(time('D')) == monday ? 1 : 0

Comment: //plot works by combining the isMonday function combined with the price to plot the line for that given condition
plot(isMonday() and midPrice  ? midPrice :  na, title="Monday Eq",   style=circles, linewidth=2, color=black)
plot(isMonday() and openPrice ? openPrice:  na, title="Monday Eq",   style=circles, linewidth=2, color=purple)
plot(isMonday() and highPrice ? highPrice:  na, title="Monday High", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=green)
plot(isMonday() and lowPrice  ? lowPrice :  na, title="Monday Low",  style=circles, linewidth=2, color=green)

Comment: this is done by pine version 1, though

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting in the comments.